# Where is Saruman's many colored cloak referenced?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, saruman

What are the specific references in Lord of the Rings to Saruman having a many colored cloak ?
I have only found the one instance of the description of Saruman when he appears on the balcony in Book Three to speak with Gandalf during the siege of Isengard.

I think there are other references, if someone knows them that would be nice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In *The Fellowship of the Ring*, during the [Council of Elrond](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Council_of_Elrond) at Rivendell;
Gandalf relates the tale of the fight which he had with Saruman in Isengard.

> ‘For I am Saruman the Wise, Saruman Ring-maker, Saruman of Many Colours!’
>
> I looked then and saw that his robes, which had seemed white, were not so, but were woven of all colours, and if he moved they shimmered and changed hue so that the eye was bewildered.
>
> ‘I liked white better,’ I said.
>
> ‘White!’ he sneered. ‘It serves as a beginning. White cloth may be dyed. The white page can be overwritten; and the white light can be broken.’
>
> ‘In which case it is no longer white,’ said I. ‘And he that breaks a thing to find out what it is has left the path of wisdom.’ – Gandalf